# run a function (from a .py file) from a linux console

Tags: python, console, ppm

maybe the title is not very clear, let me elaborate.

I have a python script that open a ppm file , apply a chosen filter(rotations...) and create a new picture. until here everything work fine.

but I want to do the same thing through a linux console like:

`ppmfilter.py  ROTD  /path/imageIn.ppm  /path/imageOut.ppm`

here ROTD is the name of the function that apply a rotation.

I don't know how to do this, I'm looking for a library that'll allow me to do this.

looking forward for your help.

P.S.: I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a relatively easy way:

You can determine the global names (functions, variables, etc.) with the use of 'globals()'. This gives you a dictionary of all global symbols. You'll just need to check the type (with type() and the module types) and if it's a function, you can call it with sys.argv:

```
import types
import sys

def ROTD(infile, outfile):
    # do something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    symbol = globals().get(sys.argv[1])
    if hasattr(symbol, '__call__'):
        symbol(*sys.argv[2:])
```

This will pass the program argument (excluding the filename and the command name) to the function.

EDIT: Please, don't forget the error handling. I omited it for reasons of clarity.

Comment: I'd add an `if __name__ == "__main__"`, so you can still import the module without it trying to do that. Also, you should look up `sys.argv[1]`, not `sys.argv[0]` (which will be the name of the script).

Comment: Cool. To be even more pythonic, you could test `if hasattr(symbol, "__call__")`, rather than checking for the function type. That would let you call a class (or any other callable object) in the same way, and saves you an import.

Comment: :-). You no longer need `import types` now!

Answer (score 1):

Use main() function:

```
def main()
   # call your function here

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Also, you need to add `#!/usr/bin/env python` (or similar) as the first line of your file, make it executable and, probably in the `if __name__ ...` block, parse the command line arguments and deal with them (probably by passing them into your function).

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to do it would be to define a big dictionary `{alias: function}` inside your module. For instance:

```
actions = {
    'ROTD': ROTD,
    'REFL': reflect_image,
    'INVT': invIm,
}
```

You get the idea. Then take the first command-line argument and interpret it as a key of this dictionary, applying `actions[k]` to the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can define in your `ppmfilter.py` `main` section doing this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  ROTD(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]) # change according to the signature of the function
```

and call it: `python ppmfilter.py file1 file2`

You can also run `python -c` in the directory that contains you *.py file:

```
python -c "import ppmfilter; ppmfilter.ROTD('/path/to/file1', '/path/to/file2')"
```